# AppleScript basic date/time format and filename

Tags: applescript, automator, screen-capture

I'm trying to wrap my head around AppleScript. I have a simple project to capture screenshots every several seconds and save them to a folder.

I found this helpful script on GitHub:

- https://gist.github.com/jonobr1/a91c166a94a65e64c9b7

I've altered it a bit in an attempt to change the file name to this format:

`screen_shot 2019-04-05 at 5.23.13 PM.jpg`

Yet, I end up with a filename like this:

`screen_shot0Thursday`

I could use some help sorting out how to properly use the date and time functions within the script.

Here is the script:

```
set dFolder to "~/Desktop/screencapture/"
set theDate to current date

do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder)

set i to 0
repeat 960 times
    do shell script ("screencapture " & dFolder & "screenshot_" & i & theDate & ".jpg")
    delay 5 -- Wait for 5 seconds.
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to do everything in AppleScript, then you should try:

```
to date_format(old_date) -- Old_date is text, not a date.
    set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to date old_date
    tell (y * 10000 + m * 100 + d) as string to text 1 thru 4 & "-" & text 5 thru 6 & "-" & text 7 thru 8
end date_format

to time_format(old_time)
    set {hours:h, minutes:m, seconds:s} to date old_time
    set pre to "AM"
    if (h > 12) then
        set h to (h - 12)
        set pre to "PM"
    end if
    return (h & "." & m & "." & s & " " & pre) as string
end time_format

set theDate to (current date)
set dateFormatted to date_format(date string of (theDate))
set timeFormatted to time_format(time string of (theDate))
set filename to  "screen_shot " & dateFormatted & " at " & timeFormatted & ".jpg"
```

*Note: With regards to AM/PM: I haven't tried this in the evening, but it should work*

It would be **way easier**, however to use `do shell script` for this, e.g.:

```
set formattedDate to (do shell script "date +'%Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S %p'")
set filename to "screen_shot " & formattedDate & ".jpg"
```

or even in one step by using:

```
do shell script "screencapture \"/Users/yourusername/Desktop/screencapture/screen_shot $(date +'%Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S %p').jpg\" "
```

Make sure to replace `username` with your actual username, and also that the folder `screencapture` exists. In summary, this results in:

```
set i to 0
repeat 960 times
    do shell script "screencapture \"/Users/yourusername/Desktop/screencapture/screen_shot $(date +'%Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S %p').jpg\" "
    delay 5 -- Wait for 5 seconds.
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

*Note the importance of properly wrapping the filename in double quotes, which then needs to be escaped within AppleScript by a leading backslash: \"*

Comment: Thank you, Asmus! Could I add additional code to handle the automatic/repeated capture of screenshots?

Comment: @Nicholas I'm not sure what you want: you already included a `repeat 960 times` with a 5s delay within your question, is there something specific you're aiming for?

Comment: I'm confused on how to include your suggestion of ````do shell script "screencapture \"~/Desktop/screencapture/screen_shot $(date +'%Y-%m-%d at %H.%M.%S %p').jpg\" "```` with my current script.

Comment: @Nicholas My bad, I had tested it with a different folder (`/tmp/`), thus did not notice my error; you should always use the full path to the folder within the `do shell script` line, so `~/Desktop` would become `/Users/yourusername/Desktop`. I've updated my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, @Asmus for the help. This error I can't seem to figure out. I've check permissions of the folder, etc.. Yet no luck.  ```screencapture: cannot write file to intended destination,```

Comment: @Nicholas, could you try if the following command works:  `touch "/Users/yourusername/Desktop/screencapture/test_file_1"` ? This should create a new empty file in your `screencapture` directory.